# What are the irreps in this canonical action of $\operatorname{PGL}_2(F_q)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the permutation action of $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$ on $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb F_q)$ by fractional linear transformations. We can consider the associated (complex) representation of dimension $q+1$.

What can we say about the irreducible representations occurring in this representation? This is probably doable because our representation is an induced representation. What I am really interested in is the following question:

What can we say about the invariant polynomials for this representation?

Comment: Do you mean to ask about composition factors?  It's not obvious to me that the representation should be completely reducible ….  I guess you also have to decide whether you really mean to ask about irreducibility, or only about indecomposability.

Comment: @LSpice The question is about a complex representation.

Comment: The action is doubly transitive, so the representation is the sum of the trivial representation and an irreducible representation of degree $q$.

Comment: Isn't the repn just the (naively normalized) induced repn of the trivial repn on the subgroup $P$ (upper-triangular) to the whole group? Among principal series, this is a little unusual in that it is reducible, containing (as @DerekHolt notes) a copy of the trivial repn, and then another irred $q$-dimensional repn (akin to a "Steinberg repn" in fancier scenarios).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, ‘complex’ was even explicitly stated in the question, and I still missed it!  Thanks.

Comment: For polynomial invariants, because it's $3$-transitive, the only degree $3$ invariant polynomials are the symmetric polynomials, of which there are $3$. But starting in degree $4$ there are way more